# How to combine a custom protocol with the Callable protocol?

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I have a decorator that takes a function and returns the same function with some added attributes:

```py
import functools
from typing import *


def decorator(func: Callable) -> Callable:
    func.attr1 = "spam"
    func.attr2 = "eggs"
    return func
```

How do I type hint the return value of `decorator`? I want the type hint to convey two pieces of information:

1. the return value is a `Callable`
2. the return value has attributes `attr1` and `attr2`

If I write a protocol,

```py
class CallableWithAttrs(Protocol):
    attr1: str
    attr2: str
```

then I lose `Callable`. And apparently I can't make the protocol inherit from `Callable`;

```py
class CallableWithAttrs(Callable, Protocol):
    attr1: str
    attr2: str
```

`mypy` says:

```
error: Invalid base class "Callable"
```

On the other hand, if I just use `Callable`, I lose the information about the added attributes.

---

This is perhaps even more complicated when introducing type variables, i.e. when the decorator must return the same type of callable as the given function `func`, as pointed out by MisterMiyagi in the comments.

```py
import functools
from typing import *

C = TypeVar('C', bound=Callable)


def decorator(func: C) -> C:
    func.attr1 = "spam"
    func.attr2 = "eggs"
    return func
```

Now what do I do? I can't inherit from a type variable:

```py
class CallableWithAttrs(C, Protocol):
    attr1: str
    attr2: str
```

```
error: Invalid base class "C"
```

Comment: `Union[CallableWithAttrs, Callable]`…?

Comment: @deceze More like `Intersection[CallableWithAttrs, Callable]` [(which doesn't exist)](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213).

Comment: Yeah, true actually.

Comment: From your `decorator`'s perspective, why does it matter that `func` is a `Callable`? It never calls it so, following duck typing, I don't see a reason for "artificially" limiting its scope to only `Callable` objects(?)

Comment: @PiCTo It may not matter to the decorator syntactically, but it does matter semantically, i.e. per the specification of the decorator. This decorator should only be used with `Callable`s. (The example here is just a minimal example.)

Comment: Do you want to return *some* ``Callable`` with attributes, or the ``func: Callable``? I.e., do you need to preserve the signature?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Good point. Preferably the second, but if not possible, the first is also fine. I've added an edit concerning that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One can *parameterise* a `Protocol` by a `Callable`:

```
from typing import Callable, TypeVar, Protocol

C = TypeVar('C', bound=Callable)  # placeholder for any Callable


class CallableObj(Protocol[C]):   # Protocol is parameterised by Callable C ...
    attr1: str
    attr2: str

    __call__: C                   # ... which defines the signature of the protocol
```

This creates an intersection of the `Protocol` itself with an arbitrary `Callable`.

---

A function that takes any callable `C` can thus return `CallableObj[C]`, a callable of the same signature with the desired attributes:

```
def decorator(func: C) -> CallableObj[C]: ...
```

MyPy properly recognizes both the signature and attributes:

```
def dummy(arg: str) -> int: ...

reveal_type(decorator(dummy))           # CallableObj[def (arg: builtins.str) -> builtins.int]'
reveal_type(decorator(dummy)('Hello'))  # int
reveal_type(decorator(dummy).attr1)     # str
decorator(dummy)(b'Fail')  # error: Argument 1 to "dummy" has incompatible type "bytes"; expected "str"
decorator(dummy).attr3     # error: "CallableObj[Callable[[str], int]]" has no attribute "attr3"; maybe "attr2"?
```

Comment: Excellent answer. What about `decorator(dummy).__name__`, do I have to add `__name__`  explicitly to the CallableObj? Same for other attributes that `functools.wraps` takes care of. Would be great to have them contained in the CallableObj automagically. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: @hans Not all callables have a function's metadata, so strictly speaking the type checker is correct here. Alas, to solve this nicely one would need true intersection types. You will have to define the `__name__` and other attributes on the `CallableObj`; it's probably a good idea to have two variants, one for functions and one for generic callables.

Answer (score 7):

Since [`typing.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Callable) corresponds to [`collections.abc.Callable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Callable), you can just define a `Protocol` that implements `__call__`:

```
class CallableWithAttrs(Protocol):
    attr1: str
    attr2: str

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs): pass
```

Comment: I've tried subclassing other `typing` protocols like `Sized` and mypy didn't complain. Is there a reason why `Callable` is an exception?

Comment: @Anakhand Note that ``Callable`` is special-cased in many ways. Most importantly, it is the only generic that accepts ``[[Args, ...], Ret]`` when every other ``Generic`` just accepts ``[Ts, ...]``.

Comment: @Anakhand I'm not completely sure, but I think it's because they prefer [callback protocols](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#callback-protocols) to be used.