# Python class extends Protocol and implements class

Tags: python, python-typing

I have defined a Protocol and a class. I would like to use static analysis to check for objects that are both subclass of the class which I have defined while also implementing the Protocol at the same time.

Is this possible with typing?

Comment: A special case that is possible is the intersection of callable and protocol: [How to combine a custom protocol with the Callable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658540/how-to-combine-a-custom-protocol-with-the-callable-protocol)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python typing module: Mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912576/python-typing-module-mixin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is known as “intersection” and has been a discussed feature [since the beginning](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/18) of ‘typing’ but has [still not](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) been introduced.