# How do I define a Python Protocol for a type that is Callable with any number of keyword arguments of Any type?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

How do I define a Python protocol for a type that is:

- Callable
- with any number of keyword arguments of any type
- that returns a value of a specified type

This is my attempt:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)


class Operation(Protocol[T]):
    def __call__(self, **kwargs: Any) -> T:
        pass


# some example functions that should be a structural sub-type of "Operation[str]"
def sumint(*, x: Any, y: Any) -> str:
    return f"{x} + {y} = {x + y}"


def greet(*, name: Any = "World") -> str:
    return f"Hello {name}"


# an example function that takes an "Operation[str]" as an argument
def apply_operation(operation: Operation[str], **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    return operation(**kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(apply_operation(sumint, x=2, y=2))
    # prints: 2 + 2 = 4
    print(apply_operation(greet, name="Stack"))
    # prints: Hello Stack
```

However, mypy produces the error:

```
example.py:26: error: Argument 1 to "apply_operation" has incompatible type "Callable[[NamedArg(Any, 'x'), NamedArg(Any, 'y')], str]"; expected "Operation[str]"
example.py:28: error: Argument 1 to "apply_operation" has incompatible type "Callable[[DefaultNamedArg(Any, 'name')], str]"; expected "Operation[str]"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I make MyPy happy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer your question about exactly why MyPy isn't happy — but here's a different approach that MyPy does seem to be happy with:

```
from typing import Any, Callable, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)


Operation = Callable[..., T]


# some example functions that should be a structural sub-type of "Operation[str]"
def sumint(*, x: int = 1, y: int = 2) -> str:
    return f"{x} + {y} = {x + y}"


def greet(*, name: str = "World") -> str:
    return f"Hello {name}"


# an example function that takes an "Operation[str]" as an argument
def apply_operation(operation: Operation[str], **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    return operation(**kwargs)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(apply_operation(sumint, x=2, y=2))
    # prints: 2 + 2 = 4
    print(apply_operation(greet, name="Stack"))
    # prints: Hello Stack
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot define a protocol that fits your requirements, because it's fundamentally unsafe from a static typing perspective.

The problem here is that although you say an instance of `Operation[T]` should be callable "with any number of keyword arguments of any type", you seem to actually mean that there is *some* combination of keyword arguments it accepts. It doesn't just accept any keyword arguments.

If you could define an `Operation[T]` protocol with the characteristics you want, then your `apply_operation`

```
def apply_operation(operation: Operation[str], **kwargs: Any) -> str:
    return operation(**kwargs)
```

would still be a type error. `operation(**kwargs)` is unsafe, because there's no guarantee that the provided keyword arguments are arguments `operation` accepts. You could call

```
apply_operation(sumint, name="Stack")
```

and that would fit the `apply_operation` signature, but it would still be an unsafe call.

---

If you want to annotate this, your best bet is probably to use `Callable[..., T]`, as suggested in Alex Waygood's answer. Specifying `...` as the argument type list for `Callable` effectively disables type checking for the callable's arguments, much like annotating a variable with `Any` effectively disables type checking for that variable.

Remember that this **disables** the safety checks - there will be no warning if you do something like `apply_operation(sumint, name="Stack")`.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Yes, getting mypy to ignore the arguments is really want I'm trying to do. I know that this is unsafe, but in my real world application, I will handle the exceptions if they occur.

I think that `Callable[..., T]` is the best solution for my problem.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful explanation and has some good caveats for my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Callable[..., T]`, as suggested in the other answers, solves the problem in the question.

If one still needs to implement a custom `Protocol` (for example if additional methods need to be added to the protocol) this can be done in the following way:

```py
from typing import Any, Protocol, TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", covariant=True)

class Operation(Protocol[T]):
    __call__: Callable[..., T]
```

See: [How to combine a custom protocol with the Callable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658540/how-to-combine-a-custom-protocol-with-the-callable-protocol)