# What is equivalent Protocol of Python Callable?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I always though that Callable is equivalent to having the dunder `__call__` but apparently there is also `__name__`, because the following code is correct for `mypy --strict`:

```py
def print_name(f: Callable[..., Any]) -> None:
    print(f.__name__)

def foo() -> None:
    pass

print_name(foo)

print_name(lambda x: x)
```

What is actual interface of python Callable?

I dug out what `functools.wraps` does. AFAIU it sets `('__module__', '__name__', '__qualname__', '__doc__', '__annotations__')` - is that the same what the `Callable` is expected to have?

Comment: Note that some of these attributes are from `object`, some of them are probably “from the class of `Callable`” (like how you can access class variables from an instance). Even a blank `Protocol` is not actually blank, it will have some of the attributes you listed.

Comment: I agree that this is inconsistent behavior on the part of `mypy`. The callable protocol clearly requires **only** the `__call__` method to be defined and none of those other attributes. Your question inspired me to open an [issue here](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14392) in the hopes of understanding the reason for this behavior. I laid out the details there. If I get a reasonable response, I may post it as an answer here.

Comment: A `Callable` object is something that can be called as a function (e.g., by having a `__call__` attribute), but there's nothing wrong with a `Callable` that has a `__name__` attribute as well. There's nothing incorrect for MyPy to complain about.

Comment: @jjramsey You seem to not understand the concept of callable subtypes. If `f` is a `Callable` and mypy complains about `f.foo`, it should also complain about `f.__name__`. _Could_ a callable have the attributes `__name__` or `foo`? Sure. Should you **expect** it to? Absolutely not. And the mypy team agrees with this. They just consider this incorrect behavior acceptable (see the issue).

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg I see what you are saying, and I checked that MyPy does complain about `f.foo`. The catch is that most things that can be called as functions typically *do* have a `__name__` attribute, even built-in functions and lambdas.

Comment: @jjramsey That may be true, but it is _incorrect_ nonetheless. Just because _most_ mappings out there are mutable (because they are `dict` types), we should **not** assume _every_ mapping to support `__setitem__`. That is why we have the `Mapping` [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections-abstract-base-classes) and why it has a distinct subtype called `MutableMapping`. I don't see why `Callable` should get special treatment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine a custom protocol with the Callable protocol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62658540/how-to-combine-a-custom-protocol-with-the-callable-protocol)

Comment: Not really. This question is about nature of Callable. Other questions is about extending Callable with attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the `mypy` position up until now seems to have been that *most* of the time, when a variable is annotated with `Callable`, the user expects it to stand for a user-defined function (i.e. `def something(...): ...`).

Even though user-defined functions are technically a [**subtype** of the callable](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-32) and even though they are the ones that define a number of those attributes you mentioned, some users are not aware of this distinction and would be surprised, if `mypy` raised an error with code like this:

```py
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import Any

def f(cal: Callable[..., Any]) -> None:
    print(cal.__name__)
    print(cal.__globals__)
    print(cal.__kwdefaults__)
    print(cal.foo)
```

Each of those `print`-lines **should** be an error, yet only the last actually triggers one.

Moreover, if we define a minimal callable class that **doesn't** have those attributes, it is treated as a subtype of `Callable` by both Python and `mypy`, creating a logical contradication:

```py
class Bar:
    def __call__(self) -> None:
        print(f"hi mom")


f(Bar())  # this is valid
print(Bar().__name__)  # this is an error
```

Their argument so far amounts to maintaining convenience for users that have so far failed to see the distinction between callable subtypes, and by extension avoiding confused issues being opened by those users, asking why callables shouldn't have `__name__` or those other attributes. (I hope I am being charitable enough with my interpretation.)

I find this to be a very odd position (to put it mildly) and I expressed as much in [the issue](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/14392) I opened for this. I'll keep this answer updated, if any new insights are reached in the discussion around the issue.

---

Bottom line is: You are right, callables *must* have the `__call__` method and *do not* require anything else.

Comment: While `print(Bar().__name__)` is an error,  `print(Bar.__name__)` is not.  
`Bar().__name__` is trying to get `__name__` from the result of the Callable, `None`, not the Callable itself.

Comment: @nigh_anxiety No, you are wrong. `Bar` is the class, `Bar()` is the instance and that instance is itself a callable, i.e. you can write `Bar()()`. Of course the class has `__name__`, all classes do. My argument is precisely that instances of `Bar` have the `__call__` method, but _do not_ have the `__name__` attribute.

Comment: Even though this occurs on `mypy`, `pyright` has the same behaviour. If more than one of the major type check implementations (`mypy`, `pyright`, `pytype`, `pyre`) all have the same behaviour, it's an issue for the GitHub `typing` repo instead.

Comment: @dROOOze Not necessarily. I've seen the maintainers of these two projects discuss issues often and in any case they may just follow the same line of reasoning for implementing this behavior in their respective programs. But I am already looking into `mypy` to propose a PR for this. So I'll know soon enough, where the root cause lies.